# Why works addr2line only for functions

Tags: c, debugging, elf

I've got `addr2line` working for function addresses:

```
$ nm -S executable | grep main
08048742 000000a0 T main
$ addr2line -e executable 08048742
/home/blablabla/src/main.c:80
```

Unfortunately it only works if I supply an address of a function, when passing an address of a data symbol (e.g. the address of a crc table) it can never resolve the file/line number:

```
$ nm -S executable | grep tableCRC
080491bc 00000200 r tableCRC
$ addr2line -e executable 080491bc
??:0
```

I guess that that kind of debug information just isn't included for data because this feature is probably intended for analyzing backtraces, but maybe there's a compiler/linker option to force this?

I want to use the output of `addr2line` to generate detailed information about how much memory size a file or module uses (instead of the global number reported by the 'size' tool).

Comment: Keep in mind that if the application allocates any memory dynamically (which is probably the case for any non-trivial application), then any estimates of size based on this kind of analysis won't be very useful.

Comment: @Michael Mior: I'm using this for size analysis of code for an microcontroller with 8K RAM. `malloc` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: That certainly makes life easier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--print-size` and `--line-numbers` options to **nm** are probably what you are looking for.

Please note that the ELF object needs to contain debugging information for the `--line-numbers` option to work.

Comment: `--line-numbers`, how could I have missed that from the manual page. Thanks!